# firewalld failed to apply rules / set_rule() failure when --reload

Tags: firewalld

I have been using firewalld without any problems for about a year now. Recently I added a new zone *docker*, to which I added the virual *docker0* interface, and added services to that zone, and that zone worked nicely without any problems as well. However, suddenly firewalld can no longer find my normal interface (wlp59s0). I believe I might have added wlp59s0 to *docker* as well. So I run

```
firewall-cmd --zone=work --change-interface=wlp59s0

firewall-cmd --reload
```

Which results in the following error message:

> Error: 'FirewallZoneIPTables' object has no attribute '_FirewallZone__icmp_block_inversion'

If I run

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

the system spits out the following:

> firewalld[6040]: ERROR: Failed to apply rules. A firewall reload might solve the issue if the firewall has been modified
>
> firewalld[6040]: ERROR: set_rule() missing 1 required positional argument: 'log_denied'

I get no internet connection whatsoever when firewalld is on. I have absolutely no idea what to do here, I cannot find any resources online about this either. Can anyone please help me?

Update: I rolled back from 0.5.0-1 to 0.4.4.5-1 and the problem no longer persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here on Archlinux. I didn't change any settings in a year. Just updated and restart and firewalld refused to start with Error: 'FirewallZoneIPTables' object has no attribute '_FirewallZone__icmp_block_inversion'
Downgraded to 0.4.4.6-1 and it works.

EDIT: Updated to 0.5.1-1 today and it's working now.

Comment: That's very interesting, because I run Arch as well, so it might be an Arch/firewalld problem.

Comment: Probably. I don't dare to update meanwhile because it's a production environment. Hope it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: Updated to latest version today and it's back to normal.